# MATCH() with search_type 1 doesn't work with certain numbers

Tags: function, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs

I've read several similar questions but I couldn't find the answer.

I've certain number values that the `MATCH()` function, with the *search_type* option set as 1, can't retrieve.

The best way to explain it, is to share the spreadsheet ([here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G7FcIZCooQXsYnjs_gEEbBeKvnb3V7UnPBV-UBozIZU/edit?usp=sharing)) where you can see in details on which columns the `MATCH()` is not working.

I don't think is some problems of data type because the *search_key* and the `range` values are of the same type.

Indeed I've also tried something that I've read in other answers about using data converter, for instance:

> If you have a numeric lookup value you can convert to text in the
>   formula by using &"", e.g.
>
> `=MATCH(A1&"",B:B,0)`
>
> ....or if it's a text lookup value which needs to match with numbers
>
> `=MATCH(A1+0,B:B,0)`

Any ideas of what is going wrong, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use "0" for the last paramenter because your range is not sorted in ascending order. 1 only works for searching sorted ranged.

Comment: Now I got the sense. Thanks.